# Restful Routing for Nested Resource with a Form with Checkbox Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

My models are:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_stores
  has_many :stores, through: :user_stores        
end

class UserStore < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_stores
  has_many :users, through: :user_stores
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root 'home#index'

  resources :user do
    resources :stores
  end
end
```

rails routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                  devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                 devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                    devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                                        home#index
             user_stores GET    /user/:user_id/stores(.:format)          stores#index
                         POST   /user/:user_id/stores(.:format)          stores#create
          new_user_store GET    /user/:user_id/stores/new(.:format)      stores#new
         edit_user_store GET    /user/:user_id/stores/:id/edit(.:format) stores#edit
              user_store GET    /user/:user_id/stores/:id(.:format)      stores#show
                         PATCH  /user/:user_id/stores/:id(.:format)      stores#update
                         PUT    /user/:user_id/stores/:id(.:format)      stores#update
                         DELETE /user/:user_id/stores/:id(.:format)      stores#destroy
              user_index GET    /user(.:format)                          user#index
                         POST   /user(.:format)                          user#create
                new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)                      user#new
               edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format)                 user#edit
                    user GET    /user/:id(.:format)                      user#show
                         PATCH  /user/:id(.:format)                      user#update
                         PUT    /user/:id(.:format)                      user#update
                         DELETE /user/:id(.:format)                      user#destroy
```

In my join table, I'm going to record User's favorite stores, stores that the user wants to favorite. That will be done by a form with checkboxes, and the stores the user already favorite will be checked.

I have two routes I am confused over. When the user clicks the button to go to the page to see it's favorite stores, should it go to:

1.`/user/:user_id/stores(.:format)`
    (If I go to this route, when a form is submitted it should Post to the path `/user/:user_id/stores`, then in the controller I would take the params `store_ids[]` and go through each store id, creating it to the database.)

or should it go to

2.`/user/:id` (If I go to this route which my form currently does, I would have to use Patch to the path `/user/:id`. At this point since I'm using Devise, I would have to create a User's controller, and update the user with `store_ids` params, along with looping through `store_ids` to create the join table entry)

I know this may be a multi-part question but whichever route is more appropriate, how would I route the form to reflect this? Currently I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :stores, as: :check_boxes, label: false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Update Favorite Stores", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

But this goes to the User Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the appropriate. The second one is for users show page.

In your form helper you can just use collection select (I'm not sure if I'm using the right syntax below):

```
<%= f.collection_select :user, :store_ids, Store.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true, class: "form-control" } %>
```